# Page switching without reload

Tags: php, html, url, button, reload

I have a Website with 2 pages and therefore I have 2 buttons to switch the page.
I want to change the Website only if it´s needed, so for example If I´m using page 1 and I click the button for page 1 it shouldn´t reload.

The first step I guess is to check the URL
$link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

but with research i couldn´t go further :/
Has anyone a idea how I can do that - it´s not important for me to use  tag.

Comment: You have to do this in JavaScript. Once it goes to PHP it's too late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```html
<button onclick="switchPage(this)" data-page="index.php">page 1</button>
<button onclick="switchPage(this)" data-page="test.php">page 2</button>
```

In order to redirect to the desired page, you can simply check the URL and the button pressed using JavaScript or jQuery.

Here is an example using JavaScript :

```js
function switchPage(page) {
        let pageName = page.dataset.page;
        let path = location.href.split("/").slice(-1); 
        if(pageName != path) {
            window.location.href=pageName;
        }
    }
```